# Execute stored procedure in button

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have a drop down list binded to a stored procedure sp_selectyear that shows the distinct years from a column in a table

ex:
2010
2011
2012

I want to execute another stored procedure sp_deleteyear on a button that deletes those rows/records based on the year selected in the drop down list. How would I do this?

Do I need to set the output parameter for sp_selectyear?

Comment: what is the datatype for years (in your table) i-e datatime or string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actual get the id from dropdownlist using c# by SelectValue property and then you can pass at as normal parameter to your store procedure like this;

```
CREATE PROC sp_selectyear
(
     @yearId (your datatype)
)
AS

DELETE FROM [TableName]
WHERE [ColiD] = @yearId
```

**NOTE:** you don't need to use the OUTPUT parameter. It can be handled using normal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the selected year from the drop-down list control's *SelectedValue* property.  So you should be able to call the *sp_deleteyear* inside the button click handler, using *myDropdownList.SelectedValue* as the stored procedure parameter.